# ideals in $C^*$ algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$ algebra and $I$ be a closed ideal in $A$. Prove that for all $a\in A$, $a\in I$ iff $a^*a\in I$. 
 I want to prove that if  $a^*a\in I$, then $a\in I$, and I know the following fact about closed ideals: Let $a\in A$ and $b\in I$ be such that $0\leq a^*a \leq b$, then $a\in I$, i.e $I$ is hereditary.  
 If I want to use this fact, then it seems trivial to let $b=a^*a$ as $0\leq a^*a \leq a^*a$. 
 Any suggestion or idea will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Yes, [closed ideals are hereditary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_C*-subalgebra). So your argument works.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in a [comment by 1015](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340867/ideals-in-c-algebra#comment734116_340867):

> Yes, closed ideals are hereditary. So your argument works.

Answer (score 0):

I think we may use the polar-decomposition of $a=u|a|$ where $u$ belongs to $A^{**}$. Then by some functional calculus, we may show that $u|a|^{1/2}$ belongs to $A$ which in turn guarantees that $a$ belongs to $I$ since $|a|^{1/2}$ belongs to $I$.